# How I can do a module.exports for a Pool of Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have been getting a problem when I want to module.export the pool variable to use it in other files. I have this program in `src\db\index.js`:

```
const {Pool} = require('pg');
const express = require('express');
//Initialize
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('fetch');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
//Global Variables
const pool = new Pool({
   connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
   ssl:true
});
//Setting
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//Routes
app.use(require('../Routes/logIn'));
app.use(require('../Routes/singIn'));
app.use(require('../Routes/forgotPass.js'));
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
module.exports = pool;
```

And then I want to require the const pool in this file `src\Routes\LogIn.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const pool = require('../db');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/usuario/:user', function (req, res) {
   //console.log("GET usuario");
   var user = req.params.user;
   pool.query(
       `select * from users where email = '${user}' limit 1`,
       function (error, resq, fields) {
           if (error) {
               console.log(error);
           } else {
               console.log(user);
               res.send(resq.rows);
           }
       }
   );
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I run the `index.js` and go to the route `ulr/usuario/:user`, in the logs I see that the program has an error that says "pool.query is not a function". I want to know how i could export the const pool to use it in other files.

Comment: Are you importing the Pool object from the library?

Comment: Yes, I didnt realize that i ddnt paste it.

Comment: Is it npm's pg library?

Comment: Yes, is it the npm's pg library

Comment: Can you console.log "pool", and see what'g  going on there? everything seems correct...

Comment: Well i did it, but it doesnt shows anything in the console log, it only shows an error saying that pool.query is no a function

Comment: When i put the same code in the index.js, it works perfectly. But when I run the same code in signin, it shows that error

Comment: Are you sure you're importing it according to your folder sturcture? maybe you have some mistake? can you try importing it explicitly require('../db'/index.js);?

Comment: When i wrote it the first time i try it in that way, its exactly the same. I searched in google before I wrote this post, but all of the ways that were there didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

Use express-promise-router

```
const Router = require('express-promise-router')
const db = require('../db')
const router = new Router()
```

Use

```
await db.query(`
     SELECT * from local
  `)
```

instead of pool.query in your router.get or router.post

The above should solve your issue - You can check the same reference here

https://node-postgres.com/guides/async-express